# Is a blank cd or dvd in the drive?

Tags: vb.net

I'm making an application, that keeps playing a wav file on loop until the cd tray is closed with or without a blank cd\dvd in the drive.
I've tried the below which i have on button1 click for now, but get the following results

CD tray open = false

CD tray closed without cd = false

CD tray closed with black disk = false

```
Dim CD_DRIVE As Boolean
Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
CD_DRIVE = fso.GetDrive("G:\").IsReady
MsgBox(CD_DRIVE)
```

if i close the CD tray with a disk with data on in, it reads true. however i need it to work with a blank cd\dvd or no cd\dvd.
I see that windows cant tell if a blank cd is in the drive.
I'm still fairly new to this, so any help would be great.

thanks

James

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.driveinfo.isready?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_IO_DriveInfo_IsReady

Comment: The reason you are getting false for blank disks is because .IsReady will see if the CD can be "mounted" (blank CDs can not be mounted and are not "Ready")

Comment: This is more complicated. Give it a look anyway [Device Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363217(v=vs.85).aspx). [RegisterDeviceNotification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363431(v=vs.85).aspx). You might find it somewhat hostile at first (and even after that). But there's worse. Look at [Shell Interfaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774328(v=vs.85).aspx) for example. `IQueryCancelAutoPlay` can be registered with `RegisterWindowMessage()` (User32), and let's you override the AutoPlay functionality.